# Measurement of parasitic y-caps

Tags: capacitor, oscilloscope

I have the following system consisting of a known voltage source \$Vin\$, two resistors to ground \$R1\$ and \$R2\$ and two **unknown** y-capacitors \$C1\$ and \$C2\$ to ground (The values for the capacitors are just for reference). How I determine the values of the capacitors?

My idea would be to connect a known measurement resistor of e.g. 1kOhm from B+ to GND and measure the time constant with an oscilloscope. This however will only give me the total capacitance \$C1 + C2\$ of the system.

[image: System]

Comment: The bridge method works well with a known C and AC signal with the C ratio as a voltage divider.

Comment: note that Vin is fixed with 10Vdc

Answer (score 3):

Note that you cannot measure any AC parameter in this circuit when you have 0 Ohm AC connections on all nodes.

This is impossible to measure in-circuit.  The ground connection must be cut.

[The only method is to measure series resonant frequency (SRF)](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjATCCsB0AMinJdApgWkuCAWWEAbLgBxiEDs80uAnLdBTPDMzJmGAFABuIthEAGYhggeFy4QLFrhbRpi%20LGhcAysJJSI0QSME7BMkADMAhgBsAzmkUQuAdwlSwkkIefvH73T73xtX3hvIQDPD1cpYIBjP3DfPGMwBDAUNMQwTBJwZOgwBgghCBIyEiFSWmkEeG4AJ2EwyIbAo3Bkb3F9OK77Jw8u0KkumLiICih%200UVMjGyMClg6CiFl%20mgIelIhKoyuesHusOG2pC4LUblRoPBMSohYUMLB6AYwEh1s4POPH4Tx6du7kIizG1EghHI8BIEM%20XAA5lcDHg4jIQo03D1LsEnD1-gdhlwAEqaFogSTZCLuE5IdwqWkKGQqM78QRNThQJosGYUh7wcqEMrQqiEaAkaAMvaeNnYTk7bgAe1YkE%20OA2lUgsFoEDGckIhCEDFwEO2JAIYANjEgtFwEHy8CYLCgCiEXCE2QZ7Aw6pU6XSECyIAAwtwABZUwSqIA)  that demands an accurate model to choose how to perform the test with added reference caps, measurement method and impedance with types of probes.

I might use a scope probe loop to a spectrum analyzer to sniff any form of noise around the battery cable.  Then add some repetitive noise to excite bursts of resonance that may or may not dampen a lot with similar film caps added to match expected stray capacitance.  Keep in mind a battery is measured in (tens of) thousands of Farads so there is a parasitic equivalent series inductance ESL that now resonates with the parasitic capacitance which is in series with that loop.

Using a comparative circuit to balance the results is known as "bridge" method. This is done by changing a known value with a separate but similar circuit and expecting the same response or subtracting for a null value with some differential method and analysis.

This is done in [many ways for other circuits.](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/worksheets/ac-network-analysis/)

Any questions?

Comment: True. Alternatively, the supply can be disconnected.

Comment: it's a simple representation of a battery system (actually Vin is 400Vdc or above). Vin cannot be disconnected as caps and resistors are parasitic. Ground is the housing of the system. so ground connection cannot be cut.

Comment: Unless you can model the real characteristics, you won't find a solution.   e.g. ESR, ESL and then excite in bridge mode with variable SRF. E.g. by adding film C's of same value and expecting SRF to reduce

Comment: I understand that you are suggesting to model the circuit using discrete elements to find a similar behaviour and SFR as the actual circuit. I don't understand why you would connect a square wave function to the circuit. Wouldn't it be better to inject a AC sweep and look at the frequency and phase response?

Comment: Those techniques have equivalent FFT responses. So either way.   But as I explained you cannot differentiate C1 and C2 as they are lumped in parallel.

Comment: On actual system i just put a known resistor between B+ and GND, which is way smaller than R1 and R2. Then you can measure the time constant of capacitors discharging and get the total capacitance value from that. It may not be totally accurate but it seems to be close enough. What do you think of this method?

Comment: yes that is simple, but it can’t measure  the difference.  so if these are Y caps for an EMI filter. assume they are equal about 4n7 so about 10nF or less together. Such that at your grid frequency the current is about 100uA. although EU specs are much higher than North American for leakage noise current to ground (250uA limit with 100uA design typ.), so they may be greater. If your limit is 2.5mA

Answer (score 0):

If there is at least some series resistance in Vin:

1. measure the series resistance by a DC resistance measurement between B+ and B-.
2. Short B+ to GND and measure Z(f) between B- and GND -> Calculate C2
3. Short B- to GND and measure Z(f) between B+ and GND -> Calculate C1

This will work only if the series resistance is stable with Frequency, which it is certainly not in a battery. But as your parasitic RC are relatively large, you can hope that the series resistance is at least constant until a few times RC.